# Dart convert Map<dynamic, dynamic> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to convert such a `Map`:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> a = {2022-04-10: [8:00, 15:00]}; //No quotes
```

To obtain:

```
Map<String, List<String>> b = {"2022-04-10": ["8:00", "15:00"]};
```

I tried to do so, but it doesn't work for me. There is no error, but if you call print, nothing happens:

```
String str = '{2022-04-10: [8:00, 15:00]}';
final Map<dynamic, dynamic> dynamicMapFromJson = json.decode(str);
Map<String, List<String>> schedule = dynamicMapFromJson.cast<String, List<String>>();
```

I am teaching this Map from Firebase:

[image]

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('call')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        Map<String, List<String>> _schedule = doc.get('schedule');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed information about what you want to do and your data. the code you shared gives syntax error.

Comment: @SalimBaskoy I have added the code to my question

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Friend, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Should it be like `String str = '{"2022-04-10": ["8:00", "15:00"]}';`  on response string?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes it will fit

Comment: @YeasinSheikh This can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your map is

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> a = {"2022-04-10": ["8:00", "15:00"]};
```

you can convert it by two ways

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> a = {"2022-04-10": ["8:00", "15:00"]};
Map<String, List<String>> converted = {};

// 1st way:
for (var item in a.keys)
  converted[item.toString()] = List<String>.from(a[item]);
 
// 2nd way:
for (var item in a.keys)
{
  List<String> _new = [];
  for (var newItem in List.from(a[item]))
     _new.add(newItem.toString());
  converted[item.toString()] = _new;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that there are no quotes

Comment: i see, please try the second way, i think it will work (i've modified it)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the magic of regex  **"it's not really perfect expression"** but it's working fine with your case
here you can matches date yyyy-mm-dd and hh: mm then replace with quoted ones

```
String str = '{2022-04-10: [8:00, 15:00]}';

 var stringify =  str.replaceAllMapped(RegExp("([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2})"), (match) => "\"${match.group(0)}\""); 
 //This step just for replace ":" with normal :
 stringify = stringify.replaceAll("\":\"",":");
 print("value:  $stringify");

  
 final Map dynamicMapFromJson = json.decode(stringify);
 print(dynamicMapFromJson);
```

[Try the code here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ad58f257a29ab133af27871855043624)